# Conditionally apply yup validation to the Material ui textfield when the react useState boolean state value is true

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup, react-state

I have a form in which if the candidate is already a graduate then he should be able to enter the year of passing in textfield, and if he is appearing(still in college) then he should check the checkbox and the field should be disabled. so When the field is disabled I do not want yup validation to work, below in the code, I want the yup validation to be in picture when the "appearing" state is true.

```js
const [appearing, setAppearing] = useState(false);

yearOfPassing:  Yup.string().required("Required"),
```

I tried below `.when`, `.then`, but its not working. Please help.

```js
yearOfPassing: Yup.string().when("appearing", {
        is: true,
        then: Yup.string().required("Required"),
      }),
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74771831/how-to-validate-conditionally-with-yup-based-on-react-state-value/, this very similar question.