# How to validate conditionally with Yup based on react state value?

Tags: reactjs, response, formik, yup

I'm trying to display an error message using Formik and Yup, based on condition if a username is already taken or not. I'm getting the response from my nodejs backend, if the response is false the username already exists in the database and I need to display an error that "it's already taken".
Validation schema:

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
    isTaken:yup.boolean(),
    username: yup.string().when('isTaken',{
      is:false,
      then:yup.string().required('Username taken')
    }), 
    password: yup.string().required('Required'),
    confirmPassword: yup.string().required('Required').oneOf([yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
  });
```

I'm trying this way but as far as I learned, this should only work if the isTaken is a value inside the form. I need to store the response using react state and use that inside Yup to render the message, but I struggle doing so.

Comment: I never used Formik but I was wondering if there's a way you can pass some context to Formik that then is passed down to the validation?

Comment: Formik has `status` prop, maybe it can be used to store arbitrary data and using it in validation? Not sure, but maybe.

Answer (score 0):

`validationSchema` can be returned from function like

```
const makeConditionalSchema = (stateValue) => {

    if (stateValue === someCondition) {
        return yup.object({/* validation one */})
    }

    return yup.object({/* some other validation */})
}
```

and in Formik later on -

```
<Formik
   validationSchema={makeConditionalSchema(stateValue)}
   // other props
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this is by making async api call within the yup validation. yup provide a 'test' which you can use as follows.

```
         username: yup
            .string()
            .required('username is required')
            .test('checkIfTaken',
                'user name is taken, try something else',
                function (value) {
                    //if cur value is empty its not allowed
                    if (value === "") return true;

                    //make api call to check if username is taken
                    //using fetch etc. here we are just using timeout
                    //api example: fetch(`{baseURI}/checkDuplicate?username=${value}`).then(....)
                    

                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        const randomInt = generateRandomInt();
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            if (randomInt % 2 == 0) {
                                resolve(true);
                            } else {
                                resolve(false)
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                    })
                }),
```