# Is there a way to get yup schema to read state from elsewhere in a react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-context, yup

**Context:** I'm trying to build a basic todo list app using react and typescript as a learning exercise. I have my yup schema defined in a file called index.tsx and my state for my whole app is defined in my App.tsx component. I am using `createContext/useContext` to prop drill into other components. I'm using yup and formik to validate my user input in my form components (working just fine).

**Problem:** I want to write a custom test in yup that checks to see if the name of a project in my todo list already exists in the `allProjects` state in App.tsx. This is to prevent the user from creating a second project of the same name that already exists, thus avoiding an error. However, I'm not sure how to do this or if it is even possible / if there is an easier solution I'm not aware of.

**I have tried:** This is my current code that doesn't work. I tried to pass in context and then a test method to see if the name already exists inside the allProjects data (project names are keys in this object)

```
import * as yup from "yup";
import parse from "date-fns/parse";
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import { AllContext } from "../App";


//try useContext to read state declared in App.tsx
const {allProjects, selectedProject, currentTask} = React.useContext(AllContext);
const [allProjectsCopy, setAllProjects] = allProjects;
let keys = Object.keys(allProjectsCopy);


export const projectNameSchema = yup.object().shape({
    projectName: yup
    .string()
    .min(2)
    .test('project-exists', 'Project already exists', value => !(keys.includes(value)))
    .required("Required"),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be best practice as I am very new to using these, but I figured out a solution that worked for my needs so I wanted to post it in case anyone has a similar problem in the future.

It seemed impossible to get data from state into my yup schema within index.tsx, so I just solved it in the opposite way by importing my custom schema into my component as a function that returned two different schemas based on a condition.

**Index.jsx**

```
import * as yup from "yup";
import parse from "date-fns/parse";


export function conditionalEditProjectNameSchema(stateValue: any){
  //make sure the object isn't null or Object.keys will cause an error
  if (!(stateValue === null)) {
      let keys = Object.keys(stateValue);
      return yup.object({
        projectName: yup
        .string()
        .min(2).test('project-exists', 'Project already exists', value => !(keys.includes(value as string)))
        .required("Required"),
      })
  } else{
    return yup.object({
      projectName: yup
        .string()
        .min(2)
        .required("Required"),
    })
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import { AllContext } from "../App";
import { conditionalEditProjectNameSchema } from "../schemas";
import * as yup from "yup";

export default function EditProjectForm(props: any){
    //useContext gets state from App.tsx
    const {allProjects, selectedProject, currentTask} = React.useContext(AllContext);
    const [allProjectsCopy, setAllProjects] = allProjects;

    let editProjectSchema = conditionalEditProjectNameSchema(allProjectsCopy);

return (
        <div className="edit-form-project-name">
          <button onClick={props.handleClick} aria-label="Close Form">X</button>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              projectName: ''
            }}
            validationSchema={editProjectSchema}
            onSubmit={/*fn here*/}
          >
            {/*form code goes here*/}
          </Formik>
        </div>
}
```

LINK:
If you still need more help with this issue, [this post helped me figure out my problem too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74771831/how-to-validate-conditionally-with-yup-based-on-react-state-value/75377427#75377427)